# How to use findElementsByIosNsPredicate?

Tags: selenium, nspredicate, xctest, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

> Appium 1.6
>
> IOS9.3

I used to find iOS element like:

```
findElementByIosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0].cells()[1].collectionViews()[0].cells()[0]")
```

But in `XCUITest`, how to use `findElementsByIosNsPredicate` like that? How to write the predicate string ?

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can try to use something like:

```swift
XCUIApplication().tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 1).collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 0)
```

But I strongly recommend adding `accessibilityIdentifier` to the UI elements and use it directly:

```swift
XCUIApplication().cells["cellAccessibilityIdentifier"]
```